# Agrega elementos a un array sin repetirse

Tags: javascript, array

Buen día, estoy trabajando con *javascript vainilla* y quiero generar 10 cartas con valores distintos sin repetirse. Para generar las cartas estoy usando esta funcion

```js
    function generarCartas() {
  let barajadecartas = ["Verde", "Rojo"];
  let valordecartas = [2, 3, 4, 5, "Rey"];

  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    let numeroAleatorio = parseInt(Math.random() * barajadecartas.length);
    let tipocarta = barajadecartas[numeroAleatorio];
    numeroAleatorio = parseInt(Math.random() * valordecartas.length);
    let valordecarta = valordecartas[numeroAleatorio];

    //verificara si el historial ya fue creado sino existe guarda la carta directamente
    if (existeHistorial) {
      verificarCartas(tipocarta, valordecarta);
    } else {
      historialCartas(tipocarta, valordecarta);
    }
  }
}
```

Con esa función planeo generar combinaciones como: `cartas{Rojo 5, Verde 4, Rojo 3, Verde 5}`. Pero no logro que no se repitan los colores y valores de las cartas ejemplo: `{Rojo 4, Rojo 4, Verde 3}`

Mi función para verificar si esta repetida es esta

```js
 let mazocartas = [];
  function verificarCartas(typecard, valuecard) {

    for (let n = 0; n < mazocartas.length; n++) {
      if (
        !(mazocartas[n].tipo === typecard && mazocartas[n].valor === valuecard)
      ) {
        historialCartas(typecard, valuecard)
      } else {
        generarCartas()
      }
    }
  }
```

Y esta es la función que recibe las cartas no repetidas

```js
function historialCartas(typecard, valuecard) {
        const carta = {
          tipo: typecard,
          valor: valuecard,
        };
        mazocartas.push(carta);
// setea el historial a true para que ya pueda hacer verificaciones
        existeHistorial = true;
      }
```

Mi problema es que, cuando mando las cartas, las repite y las guarda en el array(`mazocartas`), cuando solo debería de guardar las no repetidas.

Comment: En el ejemplo que estas proponiendo tenes 2 colores 5 numeros un total de 10 cartas posibles?. Y vas a repartir las 10 cartas ? Si es asi solo recorres los 2 array para combinar las 10 cartas posibles. No esta muy claro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una forma de asegurarte de no repetir cartas es hacer una mímica de lo que ocurriría en la vida real:

- Primero crear un arreglo que representa el mazo de cartas, y tiene todas las cartas que están en juego. (`mazo`).
- Una a una, ir tomando cartas, de manera aleatoria, del mazo. Tomar una carta, significa quitar la carta del mazo y ponerla en la selección de cartas.

Al final, estás seguro que no hay cartas repetidas en la selección, además que han sido seleccionadas en orden aleatorio.

```js
let barajadecartas = ["Verde", "Rojo"];
let valordecartas = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "Rey"];
let mazo = [];
let seleccion = [];

//primero creamos el mazo con todas las cartas posibles
barajadecartas.forEach(b =>{
  valordecartas.forEach(v => {
    mazo.push(`${b} ${v}`);
  });
});

//ahora tomamos las primeras 10 cartas en orden aleatorio y las pasamos a seleccion
for (let i=0; i<10; ++i) {
  let indice = parseInt(Math.random() * mazo.length);
  seleccion.push(mazo[indice]);
  mazo.splice(indice, 1);
  //console.log(indice + " " + mazo[indice]);
}

//finalmente imprimimos ambos arreglos
console.log(seleccion);
console.log(mazo);
```

Incluso, esta forma de hacerlo, puede ser más eficiente que otras que te obligan, para cada posible carta a seleccionar, a recorrer toda la selección para ver si se repite. Cuál será más eficiente depende, en realidad, del número de cartas del mazo y del número de cartas que vas a seleccionar.

Comment: Muchas gracias esta me funciona muy bien!!

Comment: Sugiero que juegues con el código hasta entender al 100% como funciona. ;) Un saludo.

Comment: claro!, ya estoy probando varias cosas con el (:

Answer (score 2):

```js
var barajadecartas = ["Verde", "Rojo"];
    var valordecartas = [2, 3, 4, 5, "Rey"];
    //Genero maso de cartos combinando arrays.
    var masoDeCartas = armarMasoDeCartas();
    //Barajo las cartas del maso generado.
    barajarMaso(masoDeCartas);
    console.log(masoDeCartas);

    function armarMasoDeCartas() {
        var maso = [];
        barajadecartas.forEach(function (a) {
            valordecartas.forEach(function (b) {
                maso.push({
                    tipo: a,
                    valor: b
                });
            });
        });

        return maso;
    }

    function barajarMaso(maso) {
        maso.sort(function (x, z) {
            return 0.5 - Math.random();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

> Mi problema es que, cuando mando las cartas, las repite y las guarda en el array(mazocartas), cuando solo debería de guardar las no repetidas.

Si quieres asegurarte de que no se repitan valores en un array puedes hacer uso de [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/includes)

Para generar un array que tenga todas las combinaciones posibles puedes usar un ciclo `while` que se ejecute mientras el array de combinaciones no tenga la misma longitud que las longitudes de los arrays de entrada multiplicadas.

```js
let barajadecartas = ["Verde", "Rojo"];
let valordecartas = [2, 3, 4, 5, "Rey"];

const generarCarta = (arr1,arr2) => {
    let comb = [];
    let randn;
    let a,b;

    randn = parseInt(Math.random() * arr1.length);
    a = arr1[randn];
    randn = parseInt(Math.random() * arr2.length);
    b = arr2[randn];

    while (comb.length < (arr1.length * arr2.length)) {
        if (! comb.includes(`${a} ${b}`)) {
            comb.push(`${a} ${b}`);
        }

        randn = parseInt(Math.random() * arr1.length);
        a = arr1[randn];
        randn = parseInt(Math.random() * arr2.length);
        b = arr2[randn];
    }

    return comb;
};

console.log(generarCarta(barajadecartas,valordecartas))
```

*Aclarar que esto genera la lista de combinaciones **en orden aleatorio***

Esto simplifica muchas de las validaciones que hacías en tu código, además la función es reutilizable para generar combinaciones de **dos arrays de entrada.**

Saludos.