# Crear nuevo array sin nombres repetidos de un array de objetos

Tags: javascript, array

No he logrado hacer que esto me funcione. Necesito hacer un nuevo array con los nombres, sin que estos se repitan

```
const names = [

  {
    name: "Juan, Pedro, Roberto, Jesus, David, Alberto",
  },

  {
    name: "Juan, Luis, Daniel, Miguel, Roberto, Francisco",
  },

  {
    name: "Jesus, Francisco, David, Pedro, Alberto, Roberto",
  }                    
];

Const FilteredNames = [Juan, Pedro, Luis, Daniel, David, Miguel, Francisco, Roberto,Jesus, Alberto]
```

Comment: Bienvenido. ¿Cuál es el código que tienes, además del arreglo de objetos y el resultado esperado? No podemos responderte sin código.

Comment: Por favor revisa [ask] y también si puedes realiza el [tour]. Las preguntas donde no se nota ningún esfuerzo de tu lado por intentar resolverla no son bien recibidas.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Agrega elementos a un array sin repetirse](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/379940/agrega-elementos-a-un-array-sin-repetirse)

Comment: @CandidMoe en este caso es de un array de objetos....

Answer (score 2):

1.- En `name` tienes un string por lo que hay que convertirlo a una array usando `split`

2.- Se recorre el array con un map, y se hace el split quedando un array de array's (Un array que dentro tiene 3 arrays, que dentro tiene la lista de nombres)

3.- Se aplana el este array de array's usando [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat), lo que te da UN solo array, con la lista de todos los nombres (incluyendo repetidos)

4.- Se crea un [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), el cual no acepta repetidos, eliminándolos automáticamente por nosotros

5.- El Set se vuelve a convertir en array usando `Array.from`

```js
const names = [

{ name: "Juan, Pedro, Roberto, Jesus, David, Alberto", },

{ name: "Juan, Luis, Daniel, Miguel, Roberto, Francisco", },

{ name: "Jesus, Francisco, David, Pedro, Alberto, Roberto", }
];

let res = Array.from(new Set(names.map(a=>a.name.split(", ")).flat()));

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes primero intentar crear un array con todos los nombres y luego filtrar solo los que no se repiten.

Para ello, tienes que obtener todos los valores de las distintas propiedades name de los objetos que hay en el array, de cada uno hacer un split para que te devuelva un array y luego concatenar los arrays con el reduce.

Finalmente con el new Set lo que hace es devolverte todas las entradas unicas del array

```js
const names = [

  {
    name: "Juan, Pedro, Roberto, Jesus, David, Alberto",
  },

  {
    name: "Juan, Luis, Daniel, Miguel, Roberto, Francisco",
  },

  {
    name: "Jesus, Francisco, David, Pedro, Alberto, Roberto",
  }                    
];


const allNames = Object.entries(names).map(x => x[1].name.split(",").map(y => y.replace(" ", "")));
var arrayNames = allNames.reduce((a,b) => a.concat(b),[])
console.log([...new Set(arrayNames)]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar **`reduce()`** para iterar sobre cada elemento de tu arreglo **`names`** (recuerda que cada elemento es un objeto). Al ingresar a cada uno de ellos, se usa **`split()`** para separar cada nombre en elementos de un array. A cada nombre, eliminamos los espacios en blanco con **`trim()`**, ingresando con el **`map()`**.

Luego se hace **`reduce()`** nuevamente para que de lo devuelto, eliminemos los repetidos con **`new Set()`**, ya que esto permite almacenar los valores únicos. Se utiliza los **`[]`** el spread **`...`** para devolver todo en un array. Ejemplo:

```js
const names = [
  { name: "Juan, Pedro, Roberto, Jesus, David, Alberto" },
  { name: "Juan, Luis, Daniel, Miguel, Roberto, Francisco" },
  { name: "Jesus, Francisco, David, Pedro, Alberto, Roberto" }                    
];

const result = [...names.reduce((set, { name }) => name.split(',').map(n => n.trim()).reduce((s, n) => s.add(n), set), new Set())];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto es posible con un for anidado, en el cual el primero recorres el primer arreglo y en el segundo verificas la existencia

```js
const names = [

{ name: "Juan, Pedro, Roberto, Jesus, David, Alberto", },

{ name: "Juan, Luis, Daniel, Miguel, Roberto, Francisco", },

{ name: "Jesus, Francisco, David, Pedro, Alberto, Roberto", }
];


function a(p){
  let arrFinal = [];
  for(let i=0; i < p.length; i++){
    const data = p[i].name.split(",")
    if(i > 0){
      for(let z=0; z < data.length; z++ ){
        const exist = arrFinal.find( (element, index) => {
          if(element === data[z]) return index;
        } );
        if(!exist || exist.length === 0) {
          arrFinal.push(data[z])
        }else{
          arrFinal.splice(exist[0], 1);
        }
      }
    }else{
      arrFinal = data;
    }
  }
  return arrFinal
}

console.log(a(names))
//Resultado: [ ' David', ' Alberto', 'Juan', ' Luis', ' Daniel', ' Miguel', ' Francisco', 'Jesus', ' Pedro', ' Roberto' ]
```

Espero te haya ayudado saludos.

Comment: Esta respuesta no es válida, no da el resultado esperado

Comment: Tienes razon se me paso una condición ya la agrego, no elimine los ya existentes

Comment: Te falta un `trim()`...